# Last nav link being pushed away when drop down is called

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't get my last nav link to stay with the rest of them. I can do this if i set .dropdown ul li .menu position to absolute, but then the drop down links are pushed to the right and not centered. Padding-right nor margin-right doesn't resolve this issue.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jq0ut4b/)

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YgYB.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhbSv.jpg)

[Position: Absolute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDK7M.jpg)

```
.title {
  font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#body {
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown ul {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown ul li .menu {
  position: absolute;
  float: none;
}

.menu-hover-lines {
  margin-top: 35px;
  float: right, bottom;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.menu-hover-lines li a {
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu-hover-lines li:first-child a {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu-hover-lines li.active > a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* Nav transition settings */
.menu-hover-lines a::before,
.menu-hover-lines a::after {
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.40s ease;
  background-color: #932929;
  width: 0;
}

.menu-hover-lines a::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.menu-hover-lines a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Nav text settings on hover*/
.menu-hover-lines a:hover,
.menu-hover-lines li.active > a {
  color: #8e8e8e;
  transition: all 0.40s ease;
}

.menu-hover-lines a:hover::before,
.menu-hover-lines .active a::before,
.menu-hover-lines a:hover::after,
.menu-hover-lines .active a::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown li .menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown li:hover .menu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<div class="dropdown" >
     <ul class="menu dropdown menu-hover-lines" data-dropdown-menu>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li ><a href="#">Collections</a>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Autos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Extreme Sports</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Get in touch</a>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email me!"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tweet me!"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://instagram.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Message me!"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide either a link to the site or all of the relevant CSS?

Comment: post you whole css as well here...

Comment: I added entire CSS for you.

Comment: @scriptTease have you checked the output the snippet code....?It does not look like the image t=you have posted here...

Comment: @Bhuwan yeah I did, that's why I didn't post a snippet and did images because the snippet looks nothing like my html file. Even with the needed scripts.

Comment: Post your HTML file into a JSFiddle or CodePen, it's impossible to tell what the issue is since you're missing relevant HTML or CSS.

Comment: @Xhynk I added the JSFiddle at the top, but it doesn't look anything like the links as my raw html file.

Comment: @scriptTease i have added a solution below...hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `left:0` and `top:100%` to your dropdown-menu with `position:absolute`. Remember to add `position:relative` to your `.menu>li`...

I have added `.dropdown-menu` class in the dropdown `ul`...

Also I noticed that you have written `float: right, bottom` in your css which is not valid...

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.menu>li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a {}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul class="menu dropdown menu-hover-lines" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Collections</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Autos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Extreme Sports</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Get in touch</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email me!"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tweet me!"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://instagram.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Message me!"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```